# What are different possible values for POSIX::uname() release number on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, uname

I want to determine which version of Windows I'm on using `POSIX::uname`. I know it returns 6.2 on Windows 2012. I found a table of these values, Windows version and corresponding release number but I can't find it anymore. I've been searching the documentation, and I'm not able to run uname on every operating system to test it right now. Does anyone have a link or know which numbers correspond to which version of Windows?

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlport.html

http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows, `POSIX::uname` obtains its information from [`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) whose parameter's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) contains a table.

The [Win32](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32) module provides more user-friendly calls.

```
>perl -MWin32 -E"say Win32::GetOSDisplayName()"
Windows 7 Professional (64-bit) Service Pack 1
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! That's not the table I found before but it has the same information.